# How to call a method just before an app is closed?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I have a variable who contains data that can change when user is using app.
My goal is to store those data in SharedPrefs just before user is closing app,
  I was thinking about something like

```
OnStop()  {
Preferences.edit()... }
```

but i don't know  the correct syntax ...
thanks in advance guys

Comment: onPause() & onStop() are safer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your data in SavedPrefs in onStop Method.

Syntex will be like

In onStop Method

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saved_values.edit();
    edit.putString("key", "stringToBeSaved")

    editor.commit();
}
```

And then to retrive your data in onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String foo = saved_values.getString("key", "default_string");
}
```

***Remember the key should be same.***

For more info check out Android docs on

Shared Preferences: [Save key-value data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)
Android Lifecycle: [Understand the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

`Activity.onStop()` is called just before the app is completely closed (kicked from recents)
You should probably use `Activity.onPause()` to save your preferences as it will also be called when the user just switches to another app.

Further information:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: this might now be true if you perform an activity change the old activity could be stopped depending on with which flags you're starting the new activity. Activity is not Application. If we're talking about SingleActivityApplication, than ok, otherwise, pay attention

Comment: i just guessed based on context that that's when he'd want to save to SharedPrefs

Comment: Sure, the comment was not for you, but for the author. Just to advise him :)

Answer (score 0):

You should save your persistent data in `onPause()` rather than in `onStop()`.

Then you can retrieve your data in `onResume()`.

For saving the data you can take a look at this example

```
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
  editor.putString("username", "My name");
  editor.apply();
```

And then retrience your data like this

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE); 
  String username = prefs.getString("username", "No username"); //No username is the default value
```